# How can i modify my array code to complete even if a value does not exist in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I am modifying some code i had written for my by a developer who is no longer working with us, essentially the code pulls data from a web service and parses to an array, it then looks for keys within the array and publishes associated values to an HTML table, it all works fine when each of the entries exists in the data however the point of modifying the code if to return a generic value ("not submitted") if the value is not found in the array.

background info is helpful so the use case is:

Array is made up of the sales team, they each login to a website and submit their sales totals for the day, we interrogate the web service to return the data via a SOAP call which pulls the data into the code.  The data is parsed and the values are represented in a table on a web page.

If a single sales team member does not submit data then the code fails to return any data.

I've been googling and hitting my pluralsight account to learn as much as i can about how this is done but i'm falling short.

```
class SalesResponseFactory
{
    private $date;

    //private $keyArray = ['KE', 'JY', 'OR', 'KR', 'SY', 'DB'];

    public $responseData = [];


    function __construct($date)
    {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $this->date = $date;
    }

    private function getResponseData($date)
    {
       ....
    }

    private function parserToArray($data)
    {
        $data = substr($data, strpos($data, "<DataResult>"));
        $data = substr($data, 0, strpos($data, "</DataResult>") + strlen("</DataResult>"));

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

        if ($xml === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid user credentials.");
        }

        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
        if (empty($array['Results'])) {
            throw new Exception("Holiday - No Sales Data Recorded");    
        }

        return $array['Results']['Data'];
    }

    private function alignmentArray($sales)
    {
        if ($sales['Name'] == 'Market Code' || $sales['Name'] == 'Sales Volume' || $sales['Name'] == 'Turnover Volume' || $sales['Name'] == 'Date') {
            if($sales['Name'] == 'Market Code') {
                $this->responseData[$sales['Instrument']]['Market Code'] = $sales['Value'];
            }
            if($sales['Name'] == 'Sales Volume') {
                $this->responseData[$sales['Instrument']]['Sales Volume'] = $sales['Value'];
            } 
            if($sales['Name'] == 'Turnover Volume') {
                $this->responseData[$sales['Instrument']]['Turnover Volume'] = $sales['Value'];
            } 
            else {
                $this->responseData[$sales['Instrument']]['Date'] = $sales['Value'];
            }
        }

    }


    public function parser()
    {
        try {
            $salesArray = $this->getResponseData($this->date);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response['status'] = 'error';
            $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            $response['results'] = '';

            return json_encode($response);
        }

        foreach ($salesArray as $sales) {
            $this->alignmentArray($sales);
        }

        $response['status'] = 'ok';
        $response['message'] = 'success';
        $response['results'] = [];
        foreach ($this->responseData as $row) {
            array_push($response['results'], $row);
        }

        return json_encode($response);
    }
}

?>
```

i'd expect that null values should still be output but whats actually happening is that no data is being returned to the HTML table.

Comment: What's the default value of the column in which you are storing sales count in the database? Set default value to 0 or null so that when you fetch it should return either 0 or null.

Comment: Second option is to convert to int as ``intval($Sales['Value'])``